# How do I print values only when they appear more than once in a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

`seqList = [0, 6, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 7, 0, 4, 5]`

I want to print the items in the list only when it is present more than once(in this case value 1 and 4) and I want to ignore the first value in the list (in this case value 0)

To count how many times each value is present in the list I have the following code:

```
from collections import Counter

seqList = [0, 6, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 7, 0, 4, 6]

c = dict(Counter(seqList))
print(c)
```

with output:

```
{0: 2, 6: 1, 1: 2, 4: 4, 2: 1, 7: 1, 5: 1}
```

But I want to ignore everything but 1 and 4 And the first 0 in the list shouldn't count.

The output I want to print is:

```
-value 1 appears multiple times (2 times)
-value 4 appears multiple times (4 times)
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: This is a good question! It shows clear examples and expected output.

Comment: Thank you :) I spend 30 mins writing as precise as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make the following adjustments:

```
c = Counter(seqList[1:])  # slice to ignore first value, Counter IS a dict already 

# Just output counts > 1
for k, v in c.items():
    if v > 1:
        print('-value {} appears multiple times ({} times)'.format(k, v))

# output
-value 1 appears multiple times (2 times)
-value 4 appears multiple times (4 times)
```

Answer (score -1):

A nice one-liner with list comprehension would look like this:

```
[print(f'- value {k} appears multiple times ({v} times)') for k, v in c.items() if v > 1]
```

Comment: Don't use list comprehensions for side effects

Comment: Though it is partially working, it is not ignoring the first element. either we could delete the first element or ignore it. Better c = dict(Counter(seqList[1:])) ignores the first element in the counter